# Manually specifying tick marks on a logarithmic axis in JFreeChart

Tags: java, jfreechart, logarithm, axes

Using JFreeChart I have a plot with a LogAxis with tick marks on the domain axis of an XYPlot that are determined automatically based on the width of the graph. My domain values are 0.01, 0.05, 0.1, 0.5, 1, 5, and 10; so, the tick marks do not line up with the domain values I have. Is there a way to manually specify an axis's tick marks rather than them being automatically calculated? I tried the SimpleAxis class but that seem to only supply linear-type axes, not logarithmic.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
final LogAxis logAxis = new LogAxis(axisX);
logAxis.setStandardTickUnits(LogAxis.createLogTickUnits(Locale.ENGLISH));

logAxis.setRange(0.01, 10.0); plot.setDomainAxis(logAxis);
```

Comment: This sets the axis to the correct range but does not result in the tick marks that I desire, i.e. the tick marks are still set relative to the width of the image.